# C# - RegistryKey. Why is this not getting Garbage Collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, registrykey

I have been trialling SciTech's .NET Memory Profiler. It is reporting a problem that a RegistryKey instance has been Disposed but not Garbage Collected.

[image][image]

Below is the code in question, I can not figure out why it is not getting Garbage Collected.

```
    private string CheckForServer(RegistryKey key)
    {
        string server = null;

        if(key != null)
        {
            var val = key.GetValue("Server");

            if (val != null)
            {
                server = val.ToString();
            }
        }

        return server;
    }

    public string GetServer()
    {
        string server = string.Empty;

        using (RegistryKey localMachine = Registry.LocalMachine)
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\xxxx\xxxx\Database"))
            {
                server = CheckForServer(key);
            }
        }

        GC.Collect(); //I put this here to just see what would happen             

        //..null checking on server required

        return server;
    }
```

Comment: I believe that is the static `Registry.LocalMachine` key that you are not supposed to dispose.

Comment: Thanks GSerg, this is the latest incantation of the code, it didn't originally have that but I have been trying everything to try and figure out why it doesn't GC.

Comment: Because it's not supposed to. It's a singleton, you don't dispose it or expect it to be collected.